# can't load image from model via css background-image in my html page

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

can't load image from model via css background-image in my html page , i want to load image from model that i upload it to my html page via `background-image in css`

my model :

```
class Home_options(models.Model):
    background_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',null=True, blank=True)
    your_small_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',null=True, blank=True)

    # Background img
    def get_background_img(self):
        if self.background_img and hasattr(self.background_img, 'url'):
            return self.background_img.url
        else:
            return '/path/to/default/image'
        
    # your_small_img
    def get_your_small_img(self):
        if self.your_small_img and hasattr(self.your_small_img, 'url'):
            return self.your_small_img.url
        else:
            return '/path/to/default/image'`
```

my css :

```
.header {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url('{{ home_options.get_background_img.url }}');
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url('{{ home_options.get_background_img.url }}');
}`
```

i tried to use `home_options.get_background_img.url` and `home_options.your_small_img.url` but they not work

Comment: Django template engine does not process css or js files. Nevertheless `get_background_img.url` will not work - `get_background_img` already returns an URL.

Comment: oh ok so how to show the img not url

Comment: What are you trying to do? Am i correct that `Home_options` has record for each user and background image will/can be different for each user?

Comment: i try to make two pics in same class to use them in html page , first i want background_img  to add it in css as background then i want add your_small_img in <img> tag in html , i mean add two deferent pics , one in css and other in html

Comment: it's work thanks for your time look to my answer

Answer (score 0):

get image in html file not in css | at first you must pass the model to views then use it in html using for , the code is :

```
<header class="header" style="background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url('{{ link.background_img.url }}')">
```